# Access denied for a particular user by PAM account configuration

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh

I am trying to setup a passwordless login from `machineA` to `machineB` for my user `david` which already exits. This is what I did to generate the authentication keys:

```
david@machineA:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
........

david@machineB:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
........
```

After that I copied `id_rsa.pub` `(/home/david/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)` key of `machineA` into `machineB` `authorized_keys` file `(/home/david/.ssh/authorized_keys)` key.

And then I went back to machineA login screen and ran below command and it worked fine without any issues. So I was able to login into `machineB` as david user without asking for any password.

```
david@machineA:~$ ssh david@machineB
```

**Question:**

Now I created a new user on `machineA` and `machineB` both by running this command only `useradd golden`. And now I want to ssh passwordless from this `golden` user into `machineB` from `machineA`. I did same exact step as above but it doesn't work.

```
david@machineA:~$ sudo su - golden
golden@machineA:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
........

david@machineB:~$ sudo su - golden
golden@machineB:~$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
........
```

And then I copied `id_rsa.pub` key `/home/golden/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` for golden user from `machineA` to `machineB` `authorized_keys` file `/home/golden/.ssh/authorized_keys`. And when I try to ssh, it gives me:

```
golden@machineA:~$ ssh golden@machineB
Connection closed by 23.14.23.10
```

What is wrong? It doesn't work only for golden user which I created manually through this command `useradd`. I am running Ubuntu 14.04. Is there any settings that I need to enable for this manual user which I created?

In the `machineB` `auth.log` file, below is what I am seeing when I run this command from machineA `ssh -vvv golden@machineB` to login

```
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: error: Could not load host key: /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: pam_access(sshd:account): access denied for user `golden' from `machineA'
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: pam_sss(sshd:account): Access denied for user golden: 10 (User not known to the underlying authentication module)
Jan  3 17:56:59 machineB sshd[25664]: fatal: Access denied for user golden by PAM account configuration [preauth]
```

Is there anything I am missing? Below is how my directory structure looks like:

```
golden@machineA:~$ pwd
/home/golden
golden@machineA:~$ ls -lrtha
total 60K
-rw------- 1 golden golden  675 Nov 22 12:26 .profile
-rw------- 1 golden golden 3.6K Nov 22 12:26 .bashrc
-rw------- 1 golden golden  220 Nov 22 12:26 .bash_logout
drwxrwxr-x 2 golden golden 4.0K Nov 22 12:26 .parallel
drwxr-xr-x 2 golden golden 4.0K Nov 22 12:34 .vim
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4.0K Dec 22 11:56 ..
-rw------- 1 golden golden  17K Jan  5 12:51 .viminfo
drwx------ 2 golden golden 4.0K Jan  5 12:51 .ssh
drwx------ 5 golden golden 4.0K Jan  5 12:51 .
-rw------- 1 golden golden 5.0K Jan  5 13:14 .bash_history


golden@machineB:~$ pwd
/home/golden
golden@machineB:~$ ls -lrtha
total 56K
-rw------- 1 golden golden  675 Dec 22 15:10 .profile
-rw------- 1 golden golden 3.6K Dec 22 15:10 .bashrc
-rw------- 1 golden golden  220 Dec 22 15:10 .bash_logout
drwxr-xr-x 7 root     root     4.0K Jan  4 16:43 ..
drwx------ 2 golden golden 4.0K Jan  5 12:51 .ssh
-rw------- 1 golden golden 9.9K Jan  5 12:59 .viminfo
drwx------ 6 golden golden 4.0K Jan  5 12:59 .
-rw------- 1 golden golden 4.6K Jan  5 13:10 .bash_history
```

**Update:**

In `machineA`:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep golden
golden:x:1001:1001::/home/golden:/bin/bash
```

In `machineB`:

```
cat /etc/passwd | grep golden
golden:x:1001:1001::/home/golden:/bin/bash
```

Comment: Could you show `/etc/passwd` entry for the user?

Comment: updated the question with the details. One thing is firstly I created user without any password and then later on I created the password for this golden user after some time.

Comment: Pam_sss is giving user unknown. You need to verify, how sssd is configured on your system. Some cases sssd is configured to cache credentials, so you may have to invalidate cache/restart sssd

Comment: @VenkatC How can I restart sssd in my system? These are all VM so I am not sure how it was configured as we got this system from some other team.

Comment: sysyemctl restart sssd  - should work on systemd based server

Comment: This is what I got - `sysyemctl: command not found`

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should be systemctl restart sssd

Comment: @VenkatC Still same thing.. `systemctl: command not found` not sure whether I need to install anything?

Comment: @user5447339 You need to run these commands as root/using sudo. If your system is not systemd based, you will not have `systemctl`. Instead try using `service sssd restart` (or) /etc/init.d/sssd restart (reboot of VM also might help). Pls note, it all depends on the PAM config you have.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51322/discussion-between-venkatc-and-user5447339).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is with PAM stack configuration. Your host is configured with `pam_access` and default configuration is not allowing external/SSH access for the new user `golden` ,even though your keys are setup properly.

Adding `golden` user into `/etc/security/access.conf` as below fixed the issue.

`+:golden:ALL`

To see more information read`man access.conf` which explains each field of this file. Look at examples section to understand the order and meanings of LOCAL, ALL etc

Comment: In my case I had to be added to a group that was given access permission access.conf.

Comment: Most people haven't even looked at `etc/security/access.conf`, much less edited it, so the simply answer given below is much more likely on balance. PAM pre-auth checks that the account is _not_ locked in `/etc/shadow`. Implicit in that is that it must actually _exist_ in `/etc/shadow`.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same issue and none of suggested options worked.  But I found in one of forums (https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1960510) a "workaround" which worked perfectly.

Edit `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and set

```
UsePAM no
```

While it's probably not the real solution, because something is definitely wrong with my machine (yesterday it was working fine!), this one at least works.

Comment: funny enough, I have to servers that I just did install ubuntu 20 + ldap, one I did disable PAM and worked, in the other, it is working with it; the difference: one we have passwd shadows sync, in the other we do not... so seems that disabling PAM force it to use ldap login info...

Comment: "Workaround" is a kind word for this; I would be much less charitable. Disabling PAM means that if the user authenticates using an ssh key, you won't be able to prevent them from logging in by the "normal" method (disabling their account by marking it as "expired"). In most circumstances that would be a bad idea. As other answers have indicated, the problem is likely that the user who can't log in is probably disabled or missing in `/etc/shadow`.

Comment: @martin that's why I wrote that it's probably not a real solution. In the meantime in my case it was just my working PC, without any other "users", so I absolutely don't care whether I'll be able to prevent other users to login.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same issue. pam access would deny a particular user on one machine but not others.  Eventually, realized I forgot to update /etc/shadow.

Once that's updated, the problem was fixed for me.

Comment: Dear reader: if this answer helps you, **please up-vote it**. Its simplicity is its truth, and `/etc/shadow` certainly should be _checked_ before disabling PAM.

Comment: I had added the user/group by hand, and forgotten about /etc/shadow. I found advice to use the 'pwconv' command to reconcile all entries in passwd w/ shadow. That did the trick for me

Answer (score -3):

Please add the following in `/etc/security/access.conf`:

```
-:ALL:EXCEPT root
```

Comment: Welcome to Unix.SE! Could you [edit] your answer to explain how it’s better than the existing answers?

Comment: @StephenKitt I tried both the above answers, but they didn't work for me. When I add the `-:ALL:EXCEPT root` in `/etc/security/access.conf`, it started working.

Comment: Please try to restart winbindd and oddjobd. Hope it will help. Thanks,

Comment: @IRSHADAHMEDMOHAMMED Can you explain _why_ it worked and what other security-related consequences this would have?